# Histogram over Time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to track the progress of a similar variable on a number of (several thousand) objects over time. I have several snapshots of data in the following form, but I want to show the progress over time.

```
hostname,available_updates
Newbuild,2
Greptile,34
```

A histogram is a helpful way to demonstrate this, which I have done. The challenge is that comparing a series histograms is not a good way to watch how the system has changed.

I'm thinking of a 3-axis plot: x is time, y is 'bins', and z (color?) would be 'count'. The idea there being that certain trends would become clear.

Example expected trend: extreme count cases remain generally the same (they're broken or stuck), or trend down with specific offsets. Center count cases trend down incredibly (they get patched).

I can't see anything in Excel 2016 to plot this, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I've never heard of histograms over time, and I'm guessing its not a common convention, which means using it will require your audience to learn while using it (which may not be a problem if it's for your own data analysis).  Also, a common problem with the typical Excel 3-d chart is that values in back are obscured by values in front, and perspective skews the ability to compare.  Have you considered using a variation of a line/area chart (commonly used for time series data)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, dav. I could use a line/area chart, but I'm not sure how I'd contain all 3 pieces of information-- time, count of updates, and count of machines.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power View feature for this.  It has bubble and scatter charts which can be animated over time:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Bubble-and-scatter-charts-in-Power-View-bae4a433-afae-46eb-9a28-2fe09abb2a8d

The bubble chart lets you add a 4th variable, to drive the size of the bubbles.

Power View is still there in Excel 2016, but has been buried and made fiendishly difficult to turn on:

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Turn-on-Power-View-in-Excel-2016-for-Windows-f8fc21a6-08fc-407a-8a91-643fa848729a

If you prefer a cloud solution, you could look at www.powerbi.com, which is where Microsoft have migrated this functionality.